# .htaccess Rewrite to Image Without Knowing Extension

Tags: regex, image, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url that I need to point to a specific image file. There will never be 2 images with the same name but just different extensions.

Basically there is subdirectory that has only images. The url to an image will be something like `example.com/uploads/abc12345/` where `abc12345` is the key. On the server this image is named `abc12345.jpg` but from the user's end I don't know the image's extension. So the image could be `abc12345.png` or `abc12345.gif` and so on for a few image extensions.

I've tried the following which works fine for `jpg`s but won't for any other extension. I'm not sure how to either find the image's extension on the server and use that one or iterate through all the extensions until `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` is false.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)/$ $1.jpg
```

Outside of using .htaccess I could easily use php for this but would like to know if it's possible without it.

Just for this use case lets say the possible extensions are: `jpg`,`png`,`gif`,`tiff`,`bmp`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It needs to be done with a series of rewrite rules (one per image extension):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.jpg -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^uploads/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.jpg [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.gif -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^uploads/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.gif [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.jpeg -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^uploads/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.jpeg [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.tiff -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^uploads/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.tiff [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.png -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^uploads/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.png [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.bmp -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^uploads/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.bmp [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thats perfect `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.bmp -f [NC]` is the magical little line I was missing. Thanks.

Comment: Long live the rewrite king. :)

Comment: @anubhava Just tried on a server and got `[warn] RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported and will be ignored.` 6 times when starting it. I've been looking for a reason but can't find anything. I thought I'd ask if you knew anything about it before I ask another question.

Comment: Might be due to older versions of Apache. Just remove `[NC]` from all these lines: `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.bmp -f [NC]` to make them `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.bmp -f`

Comment: @anubhava That appeared to work. Thank you for all your help.